# Mix characters from various fonts (in text mode)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, pdftex

I'm using `classico` as my everyday font, together with `\usepackage[EULERGREEK]{sansmath}\sansmath`  when there are formulas. My problem is: I don't like the shape of the "equals" sign of classico. I find it much too narrow, e.g. in a `\Longrightarrow`, but also quite everywhere else. ([MWE](http://pastebin.com/qwYHsWNm) on pastebin)

[image: simple text rendered in "Classico" font]

After quite some reasearch on tex.sx (e.g. [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font), etc) I was able to convince math mode to keep the equals sign from computer modern.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{mysymbols}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{mysymbols}{`=}
```

I don't know if this is *the right way to do it* but it looks good enough to me

[image: same text but with math-equals taken from "Computer modern" font]

> I'd like to change the font for the equals sign in text mode as well. Is this possible ?

I tried playing with even more things I don't understand (like catcodes, cf [MWE](http://pastebin.com/qwYHsWNm)) but could get nothing out of it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{classico}
\usepackage[EULERGREEK]{sansmath}\sansmath

\DeclareSymbolFont{mysymbols}{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{mysymbols}{`=}

% \catcode`==13 \def ={\ensuremath{=}}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
text: 1 2 3 = 4 5 6
\end{center}

\begin{center}
math:  $ 1 2 3 = 4 5 6$
\end{center}

\begin{center}
 arrow: $\Longrightarrow$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post your MWE code here instead of linking to one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `fontspec` way to get the equals sign in a separate font in text mode, if you compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}              % Use sans as base font

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\mymathfont}{Latin Modern Math}        % Family for math symbols
\newcommand{\mymath}[1]{\bgroup\mymathfont #1\egroup} % Command to apply family
\newcommand{\EQ}{\mymath{=}}                          % Specific command for equals sign

\begin{document}
text: 1 2 3 \EQ\ 4 5 6
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I'm looking for a solution which lets me type the regular equals sign.

Comment: Plus, if I decide to got for a `\newcommand`, then `\ensuremath{=}` will probably do the trick even in pdflatex.