# How can I include a symbol with correct size and relative position without directly using it?

Tags: symbols

I currently have a document with lots of different packages that seem to have problems to work together:

```
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{esint}
%\usepackage{gensymb} <- excluded due to error
%\usepackage{wasysym} <- excluded due to error
%\usepackage{tipa} <- excluded due to error
```

However, I want to use those symbols (most of them only once) in the document.

My current approach is to generate a PDF with only one symbol:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Additional package
\usepackage{ wasysym }

%document
\begin{document}$\Bowtie$
\end{document}
```

and then include it with

```
\includegraphics[height=12.3pt, keepaspectratio]{symbols/Bowtie.pdf}
```

however, I have the feeling that this might change the size of the symbol and its relative position to the baseline (e.g. for a degree symbol).

Is there a better way to use those packages together? Does (for the listed packages) the order influence if I can compile it?

### More specific

When I include `\usepackage{wasysm}` I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \diameter already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \newcommand{\diameter}{20}
```

I don't know how to fix that. I tried [`savesym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym):

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{diameter}
\usepackage{wasysym}
```

however, this did not have any effect.

#### MWE

This example is not so minimal ... I am working on it to make it smaller

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize} % mathlarger
\allowdisplaybreaks         % allow align enviornment to break


\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}
\DeclareSIUnit\pixel{px}

\usepackage{subfig}         % multiple figures in one
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\usepackage[raiselinks=true,
                        bookmarks=true,
                        bookmarksopenlevel=1,
                        bookmarksopen=true,
                        bookmarksnumbered=true,
                        hyperindex=true,
                        plainpages=false,
                        pdfpagelabels=true,
                        pdfborder={0 0 0.5},
                        colorlinks=false,                       
                        linkbordercolor={0 0.61 0.50},   
                        citebordercolor={0 0.61 0.50}]{hyperref}  %{0.57 0.74 0.57}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref} % has to be after hyperref, ntheorem, amsthm
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{cmll}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{skull}
\usepackage{longtable}

% Packages for symbols
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tipa}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin document                                                    %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
Here are many symbols:

\begin{itemize}
    \item \Bat from marvosym,
    \item \textblank from textcomp,
    \item $\mathds{1}$ from dsfont,
    \item $\dotsint$ from esint,
    \item $\celsius$ from gensymb
    \item $\diameter$ from wasysym,
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TS1/aer/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TS1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 82.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marvosym/umvs.fd)

! LaTeX Error: Too many math alphabets used in version normal.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.88     \item $\mathds{1}
                          $ from dsfont,
```

Comment: One approach is the `savesym` package.

Comment: If you're willing to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile, you can use the `fontspec` package to create a command to pull a single Unicode glyph from a font containing that symbol. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204761/mix-characters-from-various-fonts-in-text-mode/204815#204815

Comment: Related: [How can I use symbol fonts like marvosym in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28674012/562769)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need `\Bowtie` from `wasysym`, you can just define it by looking what's done in the package:

```
\def\Bowtie{\mbox{\wasyfamily\char49}}
```

so you just need to know what `\wasyfamily` does:

```
\def\wasyfamily{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{wasy}\selectfont}
```

So you can avoid loading `wasysym` by doing, in your document:

```
% a command to access the wasysym font
\newcommand{\moosewasy}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{wasy}\selectfont}
% here the symbols you need from wasysym
\newcommand{\Bowtie}{\mbox{\moosewasy\symbol{49}}}
```

(using `\symbol{...}` is preferable to doing `\char...` that might lead to surprises).

You can do similarly for symbols from other packages like `marvosym`.

For instance, `\Stopsign` from `marvosym` can be defined without loading the package:

```
% a command to access the marvosym font
\newcommand{\moosemarvo}{\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}}
% here the symbols you need from marvosym
\newcommand{\Stopsign}{\mbox{\moosemarvo\symbol{33}}}
```

IPA symbols from `tipa` are much more complex to define without loading the package. I'd avoid `gensymb`; its symbols are available elsewhere anyhow.

### How to find the numbers?

Martin Scharrer's `texdef` script is very handy for the job of finding out how symbols are defined. From a terminal window do

```
texdef -t latex -p wasysym Bowtie
```

and you'll receive the answer

```
\Bowtie:
macro:->\mbox {\wasyfamily \char 49}
```

Then

```
texdef -t latex -p wasysym wasyfamily
```

prints

```
\wasyfamily:
macro:->\fontencoding {U}\fontfamily {wasy}\selectfont
```

For `\Stopsign` it's similar

```
> texdef -t latex -p marvosym Stopsign

\Stopsign:
\long macro:->\mvchr {33}
```

Then

```
> texdef -t latex -p marvosym mvchr

\mvchr:
\long macro:#1->{\mvs \char #1}
```

and finally

```
> texdef -t latex -p marvosym mvs

\mvs:
\long macro:->\fontfamily {mvs}\fontencoding {U}\fontseries {m}\fontshape {n}\selectfont
```

which I converted to the better `\usefont{U}{mvs}{m}{n}`